# Can I host my web application in Cloud?

Tags: java, cloud, small-business

I have made a small web application created in J2EE which i want to develop as a "business".

Can i host it in one of the cloud services ?

Please do advice me as well on this issue. Will the cloud service be reliable over a long time ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1) Can I host it in one of the cloud services?

Yeah, absolutely. It doesn't really matter what platform you're talking about, either. Win/Lin/etc are all able to be hosted. The Cloud Computing group in Google Groups has a [good list of cloud platforms](http://groups.google.com/group/cloud-computing/web/list-of-cloud-platforms-providers-and-enablers), if you're looking for options.

Question 2) Will the cloud service be reliable over a long time?

That's a harder question to answer. The end result is that we won't know until it fails, which leads to the logical conclusion that you should select a provider with a strong background of service and dedication to clients.

One of my biggest concerns is making sure there's an exit strategy from whichever cloud you select. If you're rolling in the bucks (which nearly no one is), consider using two cloud providers much in the same way that you might have, at one point, considered using two data centers. If one fails, you've got a standby solution in short order.

Comment: Bingo - "One of my biggest concerns is making sure there's an exit strategy from whichever cloud you select." Well said Matt.

Comment: Yup, +1 for exit strategy here too.  It's also a good sign that the provider is confident in their service if they make it easy to get out.

Comment: +1: The whole "Cloud-as-Buzzword" thing is making me homicidal. I've been hosting apps at server farms for a decade, sometimes even with failover to another big hosting service and now that's become magical fluffy cloudland. All the word "Cloud" does is remove the specifics (clouds the issue?) Ask about a specific service, or a specific host, and you can have a meaningful dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2 - Windows Azure from Microsoft will provide reliable cloud computing.

Answer to question 1 - J2EE on Windows Azure? Yes! Here are some links:

Starter Kit for deploying Tomcat-based Java solutions on Windows Azure 2010-02 >  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/azuretomcat which can be used as a basis for a package that can be deployed to Windows Azure Storage only once. Then when there is a need to test a new war file, all that is needed is to upload the war file to Windows Azure Blob storage. 
This starter kit supports having multiple versions of war file in the blob storage and choosing which one should be used by changing the configuration file for the worker role.

Windows Azure SDK for Java 2010-03 >  www.windowsazure4j.org which is an open source project to provide software development kit for Windows Azure and Windows Azure Storage - Blobs, Tables & Queues